# Retreiving the child projects and updating the parent for the selected projects in Rally using API

Tags: python, python-3.x, rally, code-rally

In order to clean up Rally I want to change the parent for projects which are marked as `"Closed"`

```
--MyWorkspace
  - Project 1
  - Project 2
    - Child 1 (Status = Closed)
    - Child 2 (Status = Closed)
    - Child 3 (Status = Open)
  - Project 3
```

I want to update the parent of `"Child 1" and "Child 2" to "Project 1"` (Want to move those child projects under different parent.

```
import sys
from pyral import Rally, rallyWorkset
options = [arg for arg in sys.argv[1:] if arg.startswith('--')]
args    = [arg for arg in sys.argv[1:] if arg not in options]
server = <server>
apikey = <api_key>
workspace = <workspace>
project = <project_name>
rally = Rally(server,apikey=apikey, workspace=workspace, project=project)
rally.enableLogging('mypyral.log')
```

I am using below method to check all the projects under the required workspace

```
projects = rally.getProjects(workspace=workspace)
for proj in projects:
    print ("    %12.12s  %s  %s" % (proj.oid, proj.Name, proj.State))
```

This gives me parent level projects only

```
<id> <Name>  <status>
```

This logic doesn't return all the child projects though.

Also I am looking for `post` method to update the parents once I get the list of projects I want to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct - `projects = rally.getProjects(workspace=workspace)` returns all Parents projects.

In order to get all children Projects you need to ask about it parent:

```
for proj in projects:
children = proj.Children
for child in children:
    print ("    %12.12s  %s  %s" % (child.oid, child.Name, child.State))
```

The entire task i would solve in the following way:

```
#get object for 'New Parent':
target_project = rally.getProject('NewParentForClosedProjects')

projects = rally.getProjects(workspace=workspace)
for proj in projects:

    #get children of project
    children = proj.Children

    for child in children:

        #if project closed:
        if child.State == 'Closed':
            #Then update Parent to new one:
            project_fields = {
                "ObjectID": child.oid,
                "Parent": target_project.ref
            }
            try:
                result = rally.update('Project', project_fields)
                print "Project %s has been successfully updated with new %s parent" % (str(child.Name), str(child.Parent))
            except RallyRESTException, ex:
                print "Update failure for Project %s" % (str(child.Name))
                print ex
```